# CSS- Clip-Path border not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a shape using CSS clip-path. **jsfiddle** is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aqdasiftekhar/wLfwyb1p/1/).

*My Code is:*

**CSS:**

```
.kite {
    width: 280px;
    height: 280px;
    background: #1e90ff;
    border: 4px solid # 222; - webkit - clip - path: polygon(0 0, 52 % 0, 100 % 100 % , 0 52 % );
    clip - path: polygon(0 0, 52 % 0, 100 % 100 % , 0 52 % );
}
.kite: hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

/* Center the demo */
html,
body {
    height: 100 % ;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    justify - content: center;
    align - items: center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="kite"></div>
```

This shape needs to have a border with black color, but the CSS currently does not create the border for the entire shape but only for the `div`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31854299/4334348

Comment: http://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/MwaBBK/

Comment: can you please tell me where i am doing wrong in case of my solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add border in my clip-path: polygon(); CSS style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854185/how-to-add-border-in-my-clip-path-polygon-css-style)