# Add Border to Clipped Div

Tags: css

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53FrA/577/)

I have a div which is transformed in shape. I want to add borders to transformed Div.
If  I add normal border property it doesn't transform as div.

```css
body {
    margin:50px;
    min-width:400px;
    background:white;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
    background:rgb(122, 206, 122);
    height:140px;
    transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(2deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(2deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(2deg);
     border: 2px solid red;
    -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 150%, 82% 0);
}
div:nth-child(1) p {
    transform: skew(10deg) rotate(-2deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(10deg) rotate(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(10deg) rotate(-2deg);
    padding:3% 2%;
    border
}
```

```html
<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ullamcorper mattis risus cursus lobortis. Etiam in erat erat. Morbi venenatis quam ense pharetra sit amet lacus eget semper. Sed condimentum suscipit faucibus.</p></div>
```

Please guide on how to add border to transformed Div.

Comment: But it is working fine at my end when I give border to `div:nth-child(1)` class

Comment: add border to `div:nth-child(1)` instead of `div:nth-child(1) p`... does that work for you?

Comment: Please check updated fiddle and snippet

Comment: -webkit-clip-path is removing border from one side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `-webkit-clip-path` value to this and then it works fine, do add vendor prefixes such as `-webkit-, -moz-, -ms-, -o-` to clip-path, because many browsers have partial support to this property.

```
-webkit-clip-path:polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 82% 0);
```

```css
body {
    margin:50px;
    background:white;
}
div{
   min-width:400px;
   height:auto;
    background:rgb(122, 206, 122);
    transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(2deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(2deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(2deg);
    border: 2px solid red;
    -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 82% 0);
    padding:10px;
}
div > p {
    transform: skew(10deg) rotate(-2deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(10deg) rotate(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(10deg) rotate(-2deg);
    padding:3% 2%;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ullamcorper mattis risus cursus lobortis. Etiam in erat erat. Morbi venenatis quam enim, elementum bibendum elit sollicitudin mollis. Integer rutrum orci sed cursus consectetur. Aliquam vitae consequat augue. Suspendisse pharetra sit amet lacus eget semper. Sed condimentum suscipit faucibus.</p></div>
```

Comment: I ended up using 
border-top-right-radius 
instead of -webkit-clip-path.

It gives kind of same shape with borders.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @SwatiMaheshwari Okay but that might have got some curve shape at top-right. Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving border to `div:nth-child(1)`

Comment: Please check updated fiddle and snippet. 
-webkit-clip-path is removing border from one side

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Look this : [How to add border in my clip-path: polygon(); CSS style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854185/how-to-add-border-in-my-clip-path-polygon-css-style)

Is that's you want ?

```css
body {
    margin:50px;
    min-width:400px;
    background:white;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
    background:rgb(122, 206, 122);
    height:140px;
    transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(2deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(2deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(2deg);
    border: solid 1px black;
}
div:nth-child(1) p {
    transform: skew(10deg) rotate(-2deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(10deg) rotate(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(10deg) rotate(-2deg);
    padding:3% 2%;
}
```

```html
<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ullamcorper mattis risus cursus lobortis. Etiam in erat erat. Morbi venenatis quam ense pharetra sit amet lacus eget semper. Sed condimentum suscipit faucibus.</p></div>
```

Comment: Please check updated fiddle and snippet. 
-webkit-clip-path is removing border from one side

Comment: Look this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854185/how-to-add-border-in-my-clip-path-polygon-css-style

Comment: I ended up using 
border-top-right-radius 
instead of -webkit-clip-path.

It gives kind of same shape with borders.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tp1g77ta/

Add

```
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Use a class or an ID to apply only to that div.

Comment: Please check updated fiddle and snippet. 
-webkit-clip-path is removing border from one side