# CSS3 clip-path - add outline and pebble shapes?

Tags: html, css, clip-path

How can I clip image with an outline?

I am using the guide from [here](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/).

css:

```
clip-polygon {
  clip-path: polygon(5% 5%, 100% 0%, 100% 75%, 75% 75%, 75% 100%, 50% 75%, 0% 75%);
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg" alt="" class="clip-polygon">
```

Result:

[image]

It the border/ outline does not follow the clipped shape at all.

Is it achievable?

Also, how can I clip with more curved like pebbles, something like:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854185/how-to-add-border-in-my-clip-path-polygon-css-style/31854299#31854299 would help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add border in my clip-path: polygon(); CSS style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854185/how-to-add-border-in-my-clip-path-polygon-css-style)