# Sharpen/Harden Blurred Edges of clip-path:ellipse()

Tags: css, ellipse, clip-path

When using clip-path to draw an ellipse the edge is always blurred. Is there a way to have a hard edge?

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
      background-color:red;
      clip-path: ellipse(140% 100% at 10% 0%);
      height:350px;
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/u7rnu2f7/2/)

Comment: Adding a border of the same colour might help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854185/how-to-add-border-in-my-clip-path-polygon-css-style#answer-44331414

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and I gave it a go but it didn't work unfortunately