# css - clip image and add border to fit in div

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I wish to clip a 80px circle from image src to add a red border (circle) around the clipped portion then fit to a div box.

Below is a example but the red border not work. I would like the clipped portion to fit to the div only but now the div size is the original image size.

```css
.my-clip {
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: circle(80px at 50% 25%);
  border:1px solid red;//wish to get a circle border around the clipped portion
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.square {
     position: relative;
     width: 300px;     
     height: 300px;
     overflow: hidden;
     border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="square">
<img class="my-clip"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Tux.svg/300px-Tux.svg.png" alt="alternatetext">
</div>
```

**Update:**
I try to use calc function to change the position but looks like the math is not correct!

```css
.my-clip {
  position: absolute;
  --x: 150px;
  --y: 100px;
  left: calc(80px + 5px - var(--x));
  top: calc(80px + 5px - var(--y));
  clip-path: circle(80px at var(--x) var(--y));
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}

.square {
     position: relative;
     width: 170px;     
     height: 170px;
     overflow: hidden;
     border: 5px solid lightgray;
     border-radius:50%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="square">
<img class="my-clip"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Tux.svg/300px-Tux.svg.png" alt="alternatetext">
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add border in my clip-path: polygon(); CSS style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854185/how-to-add-border-in-my-clip-path-polygon-css-style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the different values and you can do it with border-radius:

```css
.my-clip {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -6%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  /*clip-path: circle(80px at 50% 25%); no more needed*/
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <img class="my-clip" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Tux.svg/300px-Tux.svg.png" alt="alternatetext">
</div>
```

Comment: I try to use calc function in my updated version but looks like not correct! please help point out what's wrong with my updated version!

Comment: @lucky1928 percentage in top/left are relative to the parent element not the element