# How to make a rounded hexagon with a polygon clip path?

Tags: css, polygon, clip-path

I am trying to round the corners of my hexagon by only using the clip path. I want to stay away from the svg filters and the before and after css mess. I am looking for some sort of tool to help me figure out how to measure the clip path angles. Like Clippy, but also with rounded corners.

Comment: clip-path cannot round corners

Comment: and your question is off topic because you are asking for tools and not asking a programming quesiton

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes you can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854185/how-to-add-border-in-my-clip-path-polygon-css-style. 
I want to find a way to do this where I'm not guessing at all the percentages.

Comment: no, that's not a rounding. It's a hacky approximation, non-flexible of rounding