# How to cut element corners and keep the border in React, CSS, Styled Components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, styling

I am trying to style a button and a div in React so that they have cut corners with visible border all around them. [Currently hovered button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOu4F.png) looks like this and [styled div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLr6w.png) like this.

The problem with the button is that I wish the border follows the shape of the button and not disappear together with the corner.
The problem with the styled div is similar. I want it to have cut corner with border following the shape (marked with red line).

I used clip-path and it just hides part of the element.

---

Here is the inline code I use to style Material UI button:

```
                        <Button
                          sx={{
                            textTransform: "none",
                            backgroundColor: "#1A82FF",
                            borderRadius: "0px",
                            clipPath: "polygon(100% 0, 100% 65%, 90% 100%, 0 100%, 0 35%, 10% 0)",
                            border: "2px solid",
                            borderImage: "linear-gradient(180deg, #169EF5 0.51%, #1D7CEE 97.96%) 1",
                            color: "#FFFFFF",
                            marginTop: "12px",
                            fontFamily: "'Poppins', sans-serif",
                            fontStyle: "normal",
                            fontWeight: "400",
                            fontSize: "14px",
                            lineHeight: "21px",
                            height: "44px",
                            width: "176px",
                            alignSelf: "center",
                          }}
                          onClick={()=>action()}>
                          Button
                        </Button>
```

And here is the styled component code:

```
export const CardContainer = styled.div`
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
```

I spent several hours already searching for solutions with no effect. I tried the answers found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31854299/7114550 but if I use outer and inner containers the border doesn't look bright like currently - it's darker since I use rgba colors with opacity.

The other source I tried the most was this one https://css-tricks.com/cut-corners-using-css-mask-and-clip-path-properties/
but I can't use css variables in my current setting. I was trying to use masks from here and change css variables to numbers

```
.first:before {
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 0    0   ,#0000 calc(98% - 10px),red calc(100% - 10px) 98%,#0000) 0    0/40px 40px no-repeat,
    conic-gradient(from 180deg at right 10px top    10px, #0000 0 90deg,green 0) 100% 0/calc(100% - 40px + 10px) calc(100% - 40px + 10px) no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 100% 100%,#0000 calc(98% - 10px),orange calc(100% - 10px) 98%,#0000) 100% 100%/40px 40px no-repeat,
    conic-gradient(from 0deg   at left  10px bottom 10px, #0000 0 90deg,blue 0) 0 100%/calc(100% - 40px + 10px) calc(100% - 40px + 10px) no-repeat;
}
.second:before {
  --g: #0000 calc(98% - 10px),#000 calc(100% - 10px) 98%,#0000;
  --mask:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 0    0   ,var(#0000 calc(98% - 10px),#000 calc(100% - 10px) 98%,#0000)) 0    0/40px 40px no-repeat,
    conic-gradient(from 180deg at right 10px top    10px, #0000 0 90deg,#000 0) 100% 0/calc(100% - 40px + 10px) calc(100% - 40px + 10px) no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 100% 100%,var(#0000 calc(98% - 10px),#000 calc(100% - 10px) 98%,#0000)) 100% 100%/40px 40px no-repeat,
    conic-gradient(from 0deg   at left  10px bottom 10px, #0000 0 90deg,#000 0) 0 100%/calc(100% - 40px + 10px) calc(100% - 40px + 10px) no-repeat;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg,blue,red);
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
}
```

I was also trying a solution with pseudo-class "before" but it was also using css variables.

Can someone help to solve the puzzle?

Comment: check this: https://codepen.io/t_afif/pen/bGooZmq

Comment: I don't have an answer yet, but this is a dope question :)